# Open source technology for performance metrics storage

Tags: java, performance, profiling, monitoring, analytics

I am looking for an open source solution to store and monitor some application performances.

To be more precise, I use several Java components in the software I develop and I would like to gather performance statistics for each of these components in order to figure out on what I need to focus to keep fast processing.

The idea would be to send a message to a repository to store some timestamps (everytime a Java component starts or ends) and having a web interface to browse the timestamps, and do some analytics on top of them.

These needs seem really basic but unfortunately I haven't found anything on the web, probably because I don't know the right terminology for this kind of tools.

Could someone recommend me such a tool?

Thanks in advance !

Adrien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is [RRDtool](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/) that stores time-series data. To access it from Java, there is [java-rrd](http://oss.stamfest.net/java-rrd-hg/).

I also get the impression that you are looking for whole solution instead of just data back-end. If so, check out following open source cluster monitoring system: [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [ganglia](http://ganglia.info/) and [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/). They all have web interface. Cacti and ganglia have RRD-like back-end, while graphite has its own whisper database, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that "time-series data storing" are the keywords I was looking for! Now I am gonna check these solutions and find which one fits my needs (which is, as you highlighted, to use a whole solution)

Comment: RRD in Java is often with [JRobin](http://jrobin.org) or [RRD4J](http://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/)